# nodejs callback Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js

i'm new!
I can't cope with the problem!
Did I try adding 'return' or not?
thx!

```
'GET /edit': async (ctx, next) => {
    cache.get('user', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        var user = JSON.parse(result);
        if (user == null) {
            ctx.render('login.html', {
                title: '登录'
            });
        } else {
            ctx.render('edit.html');
        }
    })

    // ctx.redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: Which framework are you using? The function signature seems to be from koa...

Comment: @Diego Yes, with koa2

Comment: Does it fails for every case or just when the `return` is executed? By the way, i think you have to `promisify` the `cache.get` function then `await` the function and compose a response in the end.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Diego thx very much! It's all right to change 'callback' to 'promise'